Powerbi Combine files error: Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model
I've a shared folder U:\ with a bunch of files I want to combine, I get this errors after trying to apply the changes:
U:\
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The Folder 'Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model. '.
Sample File
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The Folder 'Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model. '.
Transform Sample File
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The Folder 'Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model. '.
Transform File
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The Folder 'Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model. '.
Query parameters
Parameter1
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The Folder 'Transform File from U:\' is invalid because the parent folder 'Transform File from U:' does not exists in the Model. '.
Close'.

I ticked skipped files with errors
What does it mean?
